# In Haxe, how do you read a variable name inside of a Macro?

Tags: macros, haxe, local-variables, compile-time

I'm trying to use Macros to convert some variable declarations from this:

```
function test():Void {
    var someComp:Component = __SOME_MACRO__();

    // Or...
    @getCompById var someComp:Component;

    // Or even simpler...
    getCompById(someComp, Component); //do some fancy macro magic...
    // Also, if it's not possible/easy with a variable ...
    getCompById("someComp", Component); //with a string of the variable name.
}
```

... to this:

```
function test() {
    var someComp:Component = cast container.getCompById("someComp");
}
```

I'm leaning more toward the 3rd option (shorter syntax, same results).

But I have no idea how to write the macro (should it take a String as parameter? An expression?) and how to properly return that as a macro expression.

This is the (broken) code I've got so far:

```
macro static function getCompById(someVar:Expr, typeVar:Expr) {
    return macro {
        var someVar:typeVar = cast container.getCompById("someVar");
    };
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with the code you posted is first that you'd need [reification escaping mechanisms](http://haxe.org/manual/macro-reification-expression.html) for this to work correctly - so the first change would be to use the macro escapes:

```
return macro var $someVar:$typeVar = cast container.getCompById($v{someVar});
```

Now there will be some problems with this: It's expecting `someVar` to be of type String, and `typeVar` to be of type [ComplexType](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/ComplexType.html). It's easy to get the string component from an `Expr`. It's not so easy however to transform an `Expr` into `ComplexType`. The easiest way to do that is to use the tink_macros library and use [asComplexType](https://github.com/haxetink/tink_macro/blob/e3484b41908a92509042436c1216972c4b924f31/README.md#type-tools)

So the (untested) code will look something like:

```
using tink.MacroAPI;
using haxe.macro.Tools;
macro static function getCompById(someVarExpr:Expr, typeVarExpr:Expr)
{
  var typeVar = typeVarExpr.toString().asComplexType();
  switch (someVarExpr.getIdent())
  {
    case Success(someVar):
      return macro var $someVar:$typeVar = cast container.getCompById($v{someVar});
    case Failure(error): throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm is it possible I'm using a different version of Haxe if I don't have `haxe.macro.Tools`? Doesn't seem to exist in the package (in 3.1.3 that is)